# Can I specify a composite unique constraint in Derby / JavaDB?

Tags: sql, unique, derby, alter, javadb

If my table structure would be

```
table composite_unique (
    id,
    foo,
    bar
);
```

Is it possible to alter the fields foo+bar as composite unique in JavaDB?

Does SQL-92 allow to alter `unique_index` with multiple columns (`foo`, `bar`, ...)?

Answer (score 4):

```
create table composite_unique 
(
    id integer,
    foo integer,
    bar integer, 
    primary key (foo, bar);
);
```

or

```
create table composite_unique 
(
    id integer,
    foo integer,
    bar integer, 
    unique (foo, bar)
);
```

For more details see the [Derby manual](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/ref/rrefsqlj13590.html#rrefsqlj13590)

Both statements are ANSI SQL as far as I know